# calling FacebookClient.PostAsync from silverlight canvas app generates MethodAccessException

Tags: silverlight-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am calling this from a silverlight app:

```
// docs at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post
            var client = new FacebookClient(_token);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = title;
            parameters.link = linkUrl;
            parameters.picture = imageUrl;
            parameters.name = name;
            parameters.caption = promptTitle;
            parameters.description = description;
            parameters.privacy = new
            {
                value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
            };
            client.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

This generates the following error:
Attempt by security transparent method 'SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver.CreateDynamicMethod(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], System.Type)' to access security critical method 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], System.Type, Boolean)' failed.

-- more: --

{System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver.CreateDynamicMethod(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], System.Type)' to access security critical method 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], System.Type, Boolean)' failed.
   at SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver.CreateDynamicMethod(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner)
   at SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver.CreateGetHandler(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver.MemberMap..ctor(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at SimpleJson.PocoJsonSerializerStrategy.BuildMap(Type type, SafeDictionary`2 memberMaps)
   at SimpleJson.DataContractJsonSerializerStrategy.BuildMap(Type type, SafeDictionary`2 map)
   at SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver.LoadMaps(Type type)
   at SimpleJson.PocoJsonSerializerStrategy.TrySerializeUnknownTypes(Object input, Object& output)
   at SimpleJson.PocoJsonSerializerStrategy.SerializeNonPrimitiveObject(Object input, Object& output)
   at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.SerializeValue(IJsonSerializerStrategy jsonSerializerStrategy, Object value, StringBuilder builder)
   at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.SerializeObject(Object json, IJsonSerializerStrategy jsonSerializerStrategy)
   at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.SerializeObject(Object json)
   at Facebook.JsonSerializer.SimpleJsonSerializer.SerializeObject(Object obj)
   at Facebook.FacebookUtils.ToJsonQueryString(IDictionary`2 dictionary)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.BuildRequestData(Uri uri, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod, Uri& requestUrl, String& contentType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.BuildRequestData(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod method, Uri& requestUrl, String& contentType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.ApiAsync(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object userToken)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.PostAsync(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, Object userToken)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.PostAsync(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , FacebookClient , String , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)

Comment: I got it work by using var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() instead of dynamic.
Would like to know though if there is a way to use dynamic instead (Just looks cleaner to me).

Comment: which version are you using? are you getting the same effect when using the v5.0.25 RTW? if you are getting the same error can you file a bug in codeplex.

Comment: @prabir, bug has been filed ;-) Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was a bug with the sdk at that time. has been fixed since.